# How to use Underscore to select the largest array element

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js

I have the following array:

```
var array = [[{key1: 1, key2: thing}, {key1: 3, key2: thing}],
 [{key1: 4, key2: stuff}, {key1: 2, key2: stuff}],
 [{key1: 3, key2: onlyOne}]]
```

I need to take out any arrays with less than two objects and each remaining array which could have 'n' objects should only have the object with the smallest key1. In the end I'd have:

```
var updatedArray = [[{key1: 1, key2: thing}],[{key1: 2, key2: stuff}]]
```

How can I use Underscore to get this?

Right now I've done:

```
var soFar = _.filter(_.groupBy(_.map(array, function(n){return _.find(n)}), 
"key2"), function(n){return n.length > 1});

//soFar = [[{key1: 1, key2: thing}, {key1: 3, key2: thing}], 
//[{key1: 4, key2: stuff}, {key1: 2, key2: stuff}]]`
```

This lets me get rid of the array with only one object but I can't figure out the next portion to modify each array based on a comparison of their objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an answer using undersore/lodash as the OP requested:

```
var array = [
    [{
        key1: 1,
        key2: 'thing'
    }, {
        key1: 3,
        key2: 'thing'
    }],
    [{
        key1: 4,
        key2: 'stuff'
    }, {
        key1: 2,
        key2: 'stuff'
    }],
    [{
        key1: 3,
        key2: 'onlyOne'
    }]
];

array = _.filter(array, function(v) {
    return v.length >= 2;
});

array = _.map(array, function(v) {
    v.sort(function(a, b) {
        return a.key1 > b.key1;
    });
    return [v[0]];
});


console.log(array);
```

Second approach where we combine the map and filter functions into one statement.  A little more clutter to follow.

```
var array = [
    [{
        key1: 1,
        key2: 'thing'
    }, {
        key1: 3,
        key2: 'thing'
    }],
    [{
        key1: 4,
        key2: 'stuff'
    }, {
        key1: 2,
        key2: 'stuff'
    }],
    [{
        key1: 3,
        key2: 'onlyOne'
    }]
];

array = _.map(_.filter(array, function(v) {
    return v.length >= 2;
}), function(v) {
    v.sort(function(a, b) {
        return a.key1 > b.key1;
    });
    return [v[0]];
});


console.log(array);
```

Out:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are over complicating things. This is a pure ES5 example, but is easy to convert to `underscore`' syntax.

```js
var thing = 'thing';
var stuff = 'stuff';
var onlyOne = 'onlyOne';
var array = [
  [{
    key1: 1,
    key2: thing
  }, {
    key1: 3,
    key2: thing
  }],
  [{
    key1: 4,
    key2: stuff
  }, {
    key1: 2,
    key2: stuff
  }],
  [{
    key1: 3,
    key2: onlyOne
  }]
];
var b = array.filter(function(item) {
  return item.length > 1;
}).map(function(item) {
  return [item.slice().sort(function(x, y) {
    return x.key1 - y.key1;
  }).shift()];
});
document.getElementById('out').textContent = JSON.stringify(b, null, 2);
console.log(b);
```

```html
<pre id="out"></pre>
```

And in underscore

```js
var thing = 'thing';
var stuff = 'stuff';
var onlyOne = 'onlyOne';
var array = [
  [{
    key1: 1,
    key2: thing
  }, {
    key1: 3,
    key2: thing
  }],
  [{
    key1: 4,
    key2: stuff
  }, {
    key1: 2,
    key2: stuff
  }],
  [{
    key1: 3,
    key2: onlyOne
  }]
];
var b = _.chain(array).filter(function(item) {
  return item.length > 1;
}).map(function(item) {
  return [_.chain(item).map(_.identity).sortBy('key1').first()];
});

document.getElementById('out').textContent = JSON.stringify(b, null, 2);
console.log(b);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
<pre id="out"></pre>
```

Alternatively you could use `reduce` instead of `filter` and `map` and save yourself a loop and also the `chain` wrapper.

```js
var thing = 'thing';
var stuff = 'stuff';
var onlyOne = 'onlyOne';
var array = [
  [{
    key1: 1,
    key2: thing
  }, {
    key1: 3,
    key2: thing
  }],
  [{
    key1: 4,
    key2: stuff
  }, {
    key1: 2,
    key2: stuff
  }],
  [{
    key1: 3,
    key2: onlyOne
  }]
];
var b = _.reduce(array, function(acc, item) {
  if (item.length > 1) {
   acc.push([_.chain(item).map(_.identity).sortBy('key1').first()]);
  }
  return acc;
}, []);

document.getElementById('out').textContent = JSON.stringify(b, null, 2);
console.log(b);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
<pre id="out"></pre>
```

And instead of `slice`(or `map`) and `sort`(or `sortBy`), your could use `min` and further reduce `chain`

```js
var thing = 'thing';
var stuff = 'stuff';
var onlyOne = 'onlyOne';
var array = [
  [{
    key1: 1,
    key2: thing
  }, {
    key1: 3,
    key2: thing
  }],
  [{
    key1: 4,
    key2: stuff
  }, {
    key1: 2,
    key2: stuff
  }],
  [{
    key1: 3,
    key2: onlyOne
  }]
];
var b = _.reduce(array, function(acc, item) {
  if (item.length > 1) {
    acc.push([_.min(item, 'key1')]);
  }
  return acc;
}, []);

document.getElementById('out').textContent = JSON.stringify(b, null, 2);
console.log(b);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
<pre id="out"></pre>
```

And if you used `lodash` instead of `underscore`, it offers further refinements.

Comment: The map function in your code only works if the child arrays have at most 2 elements.

Comment: @bhargavponnapalli - thanks for the thoughtful answer but the child arrays have 'n' elements; I used two as it was easier to communicate and I see I should've added that detail.

Comment: It would be useful if you state that in your question then.

Comment: @Xotic750, for me this is a pretty hard question.  I already edited the question to that affect. It was an honest mistake.  I do appreciate your help on this matter; apologies.

Answer (score 1):

Without underscore.js, using plain ES

**Step1** : Filter arrays with more than 1 children

**Step2** : Clone the array, to avoid unwanted mutation. Sort the child arrays by key1 in an ascending order and return the first element using a map function

```
array.filter((a,n)=>{ return a.length>1;  })
   .map((i)=>{  
          var a = i.slice(0); 
           return a.sort((a,b)=>{ return a.key1 > b.key1 })[0]; 
    });
```

Using underscore.js

```
 var resultArray = _.map(_.filter(arr,(a,n)=>{ 
         return a.length>1;  
      }),(i)=>{  
       var a = i.slice(0); 
       return a.sort(function(a,b){ return a.key1 > b.key1 })[0];        
  });
```